# React no longer throwing lint warnings

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, lint, linter

I am working on an application started with create-react-app and usually the compiler firehoses me with warnings every time I hit save.  For the past couple weeks it has completely ignored things like empty dependency array in useEffect and other common warnings.  Why has it stopped?  I deleted my node_modules folder and reinstalled just to see if that would have some effect but nah.

Comment: if you start a new project does it work?

Comment: The terminal doesn't show `missing dependency` warning? or just your editor?

Comment: It is working on the new app but not the old app.  Terminal throws warnings on new app, not on old app.

Comment: maybe you have some eslint settings saved globally instead of in your project folders - https://medium.com/@alberto.schiabel/npm-tricks-part-1-get-list-of-globally-installed-packages-39a240347ef0

Comment: just nodemon, snyk, and typescript... something do with typescript?